# Use external database with local multisite

Tags: multisite, wp-config

I am trying to connect my local wordpress **multisite** to my staging database. It works perfect when I am not on a multisite but with the multisite I can't find a way to change the value of the main domain url...

I have tried altering the `define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mywebsite.local' );` but it doesn't work.

Any idea on how to go about developing locally a multisite while sharing the database with the staging environment?

**Edit**

To make it work on a single site install I just alter a bunch of constant to change the main directories url like so:

```
$domain = 'mywebsite.local';
$directory = 'subdirectory' // only when needed;

define( 'WP_SITEURL',       $domain . $directory );
define( 'WP_HOME',          $domain . $directory );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR',   $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $directory . '/wp-content' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL',   $domain . $directory . '/wp-content' );
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR',    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $directory . '/wp-content/plugins' );
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL',    $domain . $directory . '/wp-content/plugins' );
define( 'PLUGINDIR',        $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $directory . '/plugins' );
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/377925/edit) to show what you do to make it work on single-site WordPress.

Comment: have you try to make domain mapping ?

Comment: If you use the same domain locally and adjust the hosts file then this is unnecessary, eitherway there'll be a major performance loss connecting to a remote database server, and security implications for exposing access to the open web

Comment: @PatJ I've just edited my question to show you how I do it or a single-site.

Comment: @Gregory That's interesting, could you point me towards resources or examples that will help me understand the subject?

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm not concerned about performance as this is just for development purposes and security is not an issue as we have other ways to make things secure. The problem I see with modifying the hosts file to point to the staging domain is that I won't be able to see the real staging website and that's an issue for our team workflow.

Comment: Likewise you can take a copy of the DB or a limited subset and change the domain to the local domain. What you're trying to do is highly unusual and not considered good practice. You can also make use of apps such as gasmask on Mac to switch the host entries to view the remote staging server. I would also be wary that if any machine has the same name, e.g. `example` then that machine is reachable at `example.local` on the local network as that's how bonjour and zeroconf work, I would avoid using the `.local` TLD as a result. `.test` was added as an exception for this purpose

Comment: Not to mention that any local caches and uploaded files will show as broken 404's on the staging server because they're stored locally not remotely, all cron jobs running twice, issues with transients expiring and race conditions, differing object caches. I know it sounds like doing this will save you time and effort, but it will not

Comment: @TomJNowell You have some good points in your comments, thanks for letting me know. The main reason for this workflow is to allow several people to work on the same website while being developped on a local environment. As I haven't found a way to version control the database this setup appeared to be the only one. I'll be curious to know what's your take on this subject?